# TouchEvent Doesn't Work anymore

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm desperately trying to solve this problem:
Only a ACTION_DOWN event triggers my method. The whole day, it worked fine, but now it doesn't work anymore but i didn't change anything.

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    boolean isReleased = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
    boolean isPressed = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
    boolean isMoved = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;


        if(isPressed){
            if(Gesture_Done){
                reset_It();         
            }
            xPressed = event.getX();
            yPressed = event.getY();
            action_timelist.add(System.currentTimeMillis());
            if(action_timelist.size()>1){
                evaluate_actionlist(true);
            }
        } 

        else if(isReleased){        
            if(!Gesture_Done){
            action_timelist.add(System.currentTimeMillis());
            evaluate_actionlist(false);
            }
            Gesture_Done=false;
        }

        else if(isMoved){
            xMoved = xPressed - event.getX();
            yMoved = yPressed - event.getY();
            checkGesture();
        }
            return false;
    }
```

Cause there's no error displayed, i have no idea how to fix it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the edited code below. I had the exact same problem just a couple of hours ago, and it was because I returned false even though I was consuming the touch events. The code below returns true if you act on the event, false otherwise.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


    boolean isReleased = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
    boolean isPressed = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
    boolean isMoved = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;


        if(isPressed){
            if(Gesture_Done){
                reset_It();         
            }
            xPressed = event.getX();
            yPressed = event.getY();
            action_timelist.add(System.currentTimeMillis());
            if(action_timelist.size()>1){
                evaluate_actionlist(true);
            }
            return true;
        } 

        else if(isReleased){        
            if(!Gesture_Done){
            action_timelist.add(System.currentTimeMillis());
            evaluate_actionlist(false);
            }
            Gesture_Done=false;
            return true;
        }

        else if(isMoved){
            xMoved = xPressed - event.getX();
            yMoved = yPressed - event.getY();
            checkGesture();
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to solve this for hours.
Have you an idea why it worked well and then stoped working? I updated java today but I don't think that this matters..

Comment: You must have changed the bottommost return false; from a return true; That's the only reason I can think of.